# How to get window.browser object for firefox in JavaScript or Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing an Angular application to check whether my extension is installed or not in Firefox. For this I used `window['browser'].runtime.sendMessage()`. It will give a `window.browser is not defined` error, so I used it through a JavaScript file, and got the same error.

Code:

```
function sendMessagePromise(tabId, item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.browser.runtime.sendMessage(tabId, item, response => {
            if (response != undefined) {
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                reject('Something wrong');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: just use browser.runtime.sendMessage ... as documented (obviously this only exists in the addon)

Comment: Why are you using `window['browser'].runtime...` rather than just `browser.runtime...`? Even if you felt that it should be the `browser` property of `window`, why not `window.browser`? I'm just curious. The question re `window['browser'].runtime...` rather than just `browser.runtime...` is because I'm wondering if there's some documentation that should be changed to make it more clear.

Comment: browser and window.browser are giving undefined..so i just tried with window['browser']

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean that you want an web service to know whether the extension is installed to the visitor's browser or not?

The object `browser` (and also `chrome`) is available only in a script bundled to your extension. You need to use generic Web API to communicate between extension's script and webpage's script. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_the_web_page